# Find patterns and make substitutions in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to look up patterns in a dataframe and make substitutions

An example of a pattern I'm looking for:

> [not] + [anything] + [more]
>
> not any more (not any more => pattern) => **not_any_more**

**Data:**

```
0    can seem form something like coherent...
1    not any more...
2    is unclear any better deal...
3    Peter won’t start if you don’t sit...
4    is unclear basic conditions any...
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

**I tried:**

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.replace(r'(not|no)(\s)(\w)(\s)(more)', '\1_\3_\5')
```

**My output:**

```
0    can seem form something like coherent...
1    not any more...
2    is unclear any better deal...
3    Peter won’t start if you don’t sit...
4    is unclear basic conditions any...
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

**Good output:**

```
0    can seem form something like coherent...
1    not_any_more...
2    is unclear any better deal...
3    Peter won’t start if you don’t sit...
4    is unclear basic conditions any...
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 minor mistakes in your code. You need to change the `\w` to `\w+` and also make the replacement pattern a raw string.

Without the plus, `\w` will only match one character.

```
print(df['Data'].str.replace(r'(not|no)(\s)(\w+)(\s)(more)', r'\1_\3_\5'))
#0    can seem form something like coherent...
#1                             not_any_more...
#2               is unclear any better deal...
#3       Peter won’t start if you don’t sit...
#4          is unclear basic conditions any...
#Name: Data, dtype: object
```